# Reactive Filter, Split and Delay after Buffering

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I am trying to change load from observable by Buffering it for 30s then shrinking list by taking only the last version of specific record id.
It will still be big object so I would like to spread the load by splitting it into few items spread over a specific interval.

If Buffer time is 30s I would like to Buffer/Shrink load then send 5 small batches each with 5s between them

Simplified flow:

```
sequence
buffer
filter
split
delay
```

```
a-a-b-a-b-b-c-b-c-b-c-b-a-b-a-b-b-a-b-c-b-c-a-b-a-b-b-c-b-f-b-a-b-a-b-a-b-c-c-a-f-a-b-s-c
                          <aababbcbcbcbab>                  <abbabcbcababbcbfb>
                          <abc>                             <abcf>
                          <<ab>,<c>>                        <<ab>,<cf>> 
                          <ab>              <c>             <ab>              <cf>
```

Real Example:

```
Record
    int Id
    int Version

notifications  
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 20000)
    .Select(list => list.GroupBy(x=> x.Id)
                        .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(x=> x.Version)
                                              .FirstOrDefault()).ToList())
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current query you have? What help are you asking for?

Comment: current query is missing Split of List from Buffer into smaller batches and spread of each small batch over period of time (5s between small batches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach. Each distinct group is subdivided to 5 subgroups using the expression `index * 5 / list.Count` as the key of a `GroupBy`, and then a `Delay` is imposed to each subgroup, with duration relative to its index in the parent distinct group.

```
IObservable<List<Record>> query = notifications
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
    .Select(list => list
        .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version).FirstOrDefault())
        .ToList()
    )
    .SelectMany(list => list
        .Select((x, i) => (x, i))
        .GroupBy(e => e.i * 5 / list.Count, e => e.x)
        .Select(g => g.ToList())
        .Select((sublist, i) => Observable.Return(sublist)
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5 * i)))
    )
    .Merge();
```

Comment: You've overloaded the name `list` in your query. Can you please disambiguate?

Comment: @Enigmativity yeap, I messed up. It should be OK now.

Comment: Really interesting approach, will give it a go, thanks